# Order by in find() cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Table Unit(id, unitNo, summary).

id | unitNo
1 | 23
2 | 25
3 | 22

In UnitsController:

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('units', $this->Unit->find('all'), array(
        'order' => array('Unit.unitNo ASC'),
        'fields' => array('Unit.id', 'Unit.unitNo'))
    );
}
```

index.ctp

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->
    <?php foreach ($units as $unit): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($unit['Unit']['unitNo'], array('controller' => 'units', 'action' => 'view', $unit['Unit']['id']));
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $unit['Unit']['summary']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($unit); ?>
</table>
```

I want to use order unitNo but the result is still ordering by id.
http://s1104.photobucket.com/user/thai92hp/media/Untitled.png.html

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('units', $this->Unit->find('all', 
        array(
            'order' => array('Unit.unitNo ASC'),
            'fields' => array('Unit.id', 'Unit.unitNo')
        )
    ));
}
```

It seems to me that you've given your order settings to `$this->set()` as the third parameter but what you may want to do is to give it to `$this->Unit->find()` as the second parameter.